# XPath.evaluate() misbehaviour after Oracle DB upgrade

Tags: java, xml, oracle, dom, xpath

We recently upgraded our database from `Oracle 11gR1` to `11gR2`. After that, the `javax.xml.xpath.XPath.evaluate()` doesn't give the expected output-

```
// SAVING YOU FROM ALL UNWANTED CODE - I've queried for data and returned to ResultSet object
java.sql.Blob blobObj = rs.getBlob("DOCBODY");

InputStream inpStr = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(blobObj.getBytes(1L, 
(int) blobObj.length()));

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(new org.xml.sax.InputSource(inpStr));

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

org.w3c.dom.Node infoTag = (org.w3c.dom.Node) xPath.evaluate("sc:configuration/sc:info", doc,
javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.NODE); // configuration is one of the <parent_tags> and 
info is <configuration> tag's <child_tag>
```

I know these couple of things for sure-

- There is not problem with the code, because it was working prior to
  the Database upgrade.
- The BLOB object is not corrupted because if I use
  `doc.getElementsByTagName()` (which returns `org.w3c.dom.NodeList`) instead of `xpath.evaluate()`, I get the
  expected output.

Which leaves me to think of only one fact - behaviour of `xpath.evaluate()` API with BLOB object in the upgraded Database.

I've tried looking for compatibility issues with this API after the DB upgrade. Any more information on this would be of great help.

**UPDATE:**

```
javax.xml.xpath.XPath xPath = javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xPath.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext()); //MyNamespaceContext is just an inner class that extends javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext

// Retrieving information available in the XML file
org.w3c.dom.Node infoTag = (org.w3c.dom.Node) xPath.evaluate("sc:configuration/sc:info", doc, javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.NODE);
if (null != infoTag) {
     org.w3c.dom.NodeList docNodeList = (org.w3c.dom.NodeList) xPath.evaluate("sc:documents/sc:document", infoTag, javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.NODESET); //documents is a child tag of info tag and document is a child tag of documents tag
     if (null != docNodeList) {
           ...
           ...
           for (int i = 0; i < docNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
/* We are supposed to enter this condition, but since something is wrong with "doc" object
 because docNodeList.getLength() is returning 0, we are not able to do so after the Oracle 
DB upgrade. Before we upgraded to 11.2.0.4, this part of code was working as expected.
 However, it still works as expected when I go with doc.getElementsByTagName().*/
           }
           ...
           ...
     }
     ...
     ...
}

private static class MyNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {

        public String getNamespaceURI(final String prefix) {
            if ("sc".equals(prefix)) {
                return "http://www.dummyurl.com/configuration";
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String getPrefix(final String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        public Iterator getPrefixes(final String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I'm extremely curious to learn what could have caused such a behaviour.

Comment: can you provide which output `javax.xml.xpath.XPath.evaluate()` produced prior to the change and is now producing(or at least specify what is different in particular)?

Comment: `domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);` - remove this line or add support for  namespace in you xpath object.

Comment: Your inference that "there is nothing wrong with the code because it was working before" seems flawed. Your code might be dependent on a bug that Oracle have fixed.

Comment: You haven't shown us the initialization of the xPath objects. In particular, are you sure that you bind the namespace prefix "sc" correctly?

Comment: I have added the code snippet.